# How can panning image without mouse clicking in qt

Tags: c++, image, qt

I have a program in Qt Creator, in this program there is a photo of the four effects (zoom in, zoom   out, panning to left and panning to right) that are selected in a combo-box. Each of these effects can be applied to the image. I've implemented a zoom in and zoom out effect but how can I implement panning effect to left or right when effect panning to left or right is selected in the combo box? In fact my question is briefly: how can I implement a function for panning picture to right or left (without any mouse clicking on the picture) when effect panning to left or right is selected in the combo box?

In [this link](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8121389192/pic.png) you can see more details.

Someone's trying to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `QLabel` to display image:

You can place your image in a `QScrollArea`. The `QScrollArea` class provides a scrolling view onto another widget. You can scroll the `QScrollArea` content by setting positions to its horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

```
QLabel *imageLabel = new QLabel;
QImage image("SomeImage.png");
imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);

scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(100); // Panning to right

scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(0); // Panning to left
```

If you are using `QGraphicsView`:

```
QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(parent);

QScrollBar* scrollbar=graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar();
scrollbar->setValue(100);  // Panning to right
scrollbar->setValue(0);  // Panning to left
```

Comment: Nejat thanks for your answer, in my program i use QgraphicsView and QgraphicsScene for display the image,how can i use scrollArea?